# saving data from a UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider

I have a tip calculator where the user is able to custom set a percentage tip per their satisfaction. For example 3 part uisegmented control split with great, good, and fair satisfaction rates. They previously set their custom tip percentage but i cannot figure out how i would save the value for the next time they open the application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Then to save a value you just need to write

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:percentage] forKey:@"percentage"];
```

Then to get the value back you would just need to write

```
float percentage = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"percentage"] floatValue];
```